# why the os.walk output has two subdirs

Tags: python

my program is

```
import os
from traceback import format_exc
import pdb
des="testdir"
def generate_cabfile(folder):
    for parent,dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
        print parent
        print dirs
        print files
        print "-----------------"
        for file in files:
            file_path = os.path.join(parent, file)
        for dir in dirs:
            chile_folder = os.path.join(parent, dir)
            generate_cabfile(chile_folder)
    print "this is over"
generate_cabfile(des)
```

my dir tree is

> testdir/1.txt
>   testdir/2.txt
>   testdir/mu/a.txt

the output is very strange,which has two dir 'mu'
output：

```
testdir
['mu']
['1.txt', '2.txt']
-----------------
testdir/mu
[]
['a.txt']
-----------------
this is over
testdir/mu
[]
['a.txt']
-----------------
this is over
```

Comment: You seem to call recursively `generate_cabfile` on each subdir. That's why it's first called with `testdir` as a root, then recalled with `mu` as root. If you had another directory in `testdir` you would have another `this is over` output

Answer (score 1):

[`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) already visits *all* subdirectories it encounters (that’s why it’s called “walk”; it walks through the whole directory structure). So you do not need to recursively call your function again for every directory you see.

Your logic would be appropriate if you were using [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) to just give you the contents of a single directory. In that case, you would have to recursively list the contents for every subdirectory too.